# Replacing Buttons linked to input boxes with checkboxes

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my current code for selecting different options and have them appearing in the box (Minecraft ArmorStand Generator).

```
from tkinter import *

default = "/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomNameVisible:1}"

NoAI = ",NoAI:1"
inputbox = Entry()
inputbox.place(x=10,y=10,width=900,height=50)

root = Tk()

def addNOAI():
    inputbox.insert(45, NoAI)

inputbox = Entry()
inputbox.place(x=10,y=10,width=900,height=50)

Button(text="Add NoAI",command=addNOAI,relief = FLAT, bg = "#eF651A", fg = "white", width= 25, height = 2).place(x=10,y=123)
root.title("WIP")
root.wm_state('zoomed')
root.mainloop()
```

What I'd like to to do is replace the buttons with tick boxes, to prevent the buttons being pressed multiple times. If they click the button, add the text, if they untick, remove it.. I'm not sure where to start with this so any hint in the right direction would be nice.

Comment: Right now, the only tag is [python].  I would suggest adding at least [tkinter]

Comment: Please edit your code in order to provide a fully [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example your `root.mainloop()` is missing, as well as the functions which should be called when clicking on the buttons. However, please do not paste the full code. Just the necessary parts in order to reproduce your problem...

Comment: You want to replace the buttons? Your code doesn't have any buttons.

Comment: You say you want to replace the button with a checkbutton. What part are you struggling with? It doesn't appear you've even tried to use a checkbutton.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a working solution, you can try it below.

```
from tkinter import *

default = "/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomNameVisible:1}"

NoAI = ",NoAI:1"
inputbox = Entry()
inputbox.place(x=10,y=10,width=900,height=50)

root = Tk()

def addNOAI():
    state = var.get()

    if state == 1: #if the state is checked
        inputbox.insert(45, NoAI) #then add the text
    else: #if the state is not check
        inputbox.delete(0, 7) #delete the text

inputbox = Entry()
inputbox.place(x=10,y=10,width=900,height=50)

var = IntVar() #sets up variable for check button

c = Checkbutton(text="Add NoAI", command=addNOAI, variable=var) #defining check button variable and command
c.place(x=10,y=123)

root.title("WIP")
root.wm_state('zoomed')

root.mainloop()
```

The only problem is at the moment, you are deleting everything in the entry box (more accurately from position 0, to position 7). I assume that there will be multiple check buttons, all adding their own strings to the entry box.

As a solution, I would suggest extracting everything from the entry box, finding the string you want, taking it out, and putting everything back in again. Here's an example.

```
def addNOAI():
    state = var.get()

    if state == 1: #if the state is checked
        inputbox.insert(45, NoAI) #then add the text
    else: #if the state is not check
        contents = inputbox.get() #gets all of contents

        position = contents.find(NoAI) #finds the first position of desired string to remove

        newcontents = contents[:position]+contents[position+7:] #gets string before the word, and after the word, and joins them

        inputbox.delete(0, 'end') #clears input box for new entry

        inputbox.insert(45, newcontents) #re-inserts the string
```

Here, when the user unchecks the box, the program finds the starting position of the string within the contents of the inputbox. Because you know how long the string will be (in this case 7), you can remove the string from the current contents of the inputbox, and place this inside a new variable. Now you have a new string, without the one that was unchecked, you can clear the inputbox, and put the new one in.

Hope this helps!